# Is it possible to use unix wildcards with Scala's ProcessBuilder?

Tags: scala, unix, processbuilder

```
Process( Seq( "rm", "-r", "*" ), new File( "/some/dir" ) ) !
```

This code will fail (`rm: *: No such file or directory`) because the `*` wildcard is interpreted as string value rather than a unix wildcard. Is it possible to change this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The glob pattern is a shell feature. You can either glob for files yourself, or execute a shell, passing your arguments to it:

```
Process( Seq( "/bin/sh", "-c" "rm -r *" ), new File( "/some/dir" ) ) !
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the proper solution. In the meantime I found `Process( Seq( "rm", "-r" ) ++ new File( "some/dir" ).list(), new File( "/some/dir" ) ) !` to be sufficient (for this particular use case).